# I need to upgrade php v5.6 to version 7.4 . What are the procedural steps?

Tags: php7

I am going to be upgrading from codeigniter 3.1 to codeigniter 4.0. I understand that I first need to upgrade php on my Ubuntu 18.03 to from v5.6.4 to version 7.4+. What are the steps I need to follow?

Comment: Please check your details; there was no Ubuntu release in 2018-March (18.03).

Comment: You are going to want to first test your PHP code on a system running PHP 7.4 (or newer) as a lot of the older syntax has been completely removed. Once you have confirmed that your PHP code works, *then* you can begin the process of upgrading PHP on the server. Otherwise you're going to have a much harder time of determining why something might be broken 